# ui-router and multi nested views/states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble doing nested views with ui-router. Currently I can go one level deep: `/pages/:page` by doing the following:

```
.state('genius.pages', {
    url: '/pages/:page',
    views: {
        '' : { 
            templateUrl: "public/views/pages/page.html",
            controller: "pageController"
        }
    }
})
```

What I then want to accomplish is essentially `/pages/:page/:subpage` but I can't seem to capture the subpage. I tried doing the following but without much luck. I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined

```
.state('genius.pages.subpages', {
    url: '/pages/:page/:subpage',
    views: {
        '' : { 
            templateUrl: "public/views/pages/page.html",
            controller: "pageController"
        }
    }
})
```

In my `pageController`, I'm leveraging `$stateParams` to capture the page parameter (**$stateParams.page**) so I'd then also like to access the subpage param by doing `$stateParams.subpage`.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way or not, but I got it working. I'm also not sure if I was over complicating things. Shrug.

First thing I did was remove the `url: '/pages/:page',` block completely. This made `/pages/:page/` work as well as `/pages/:page/:subpage` which is OK in my book.

However in my model, I was linking to things like `/pages/:page` without the trailing `/` -- by doing so, it would break. I simply updated my model to include the trailing `/` and I was good to go.

My updated state is simply:

```
.state('genius.pages', {
    url: '/pages/:page/:subpage',
    views: {
        '' : { 
            templateUrl: "public/views/pages/page.html",
            controller: "pageController"
        }
    }
})
```